# Exec on multiple files with `find`

Tags: bash, find

I tried this line, but it doesn't work:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec 'perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {}' \;
```

I get :

```
find: ‘perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\\%\\%if.+?\\%\\%fi//g" ./colophon.tex’: No such file or directory
find: ‘perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\\%\\%if.+?\\%\\%fi//g" ./glossary.tex’: No such file or directory
```

But the following works:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//gs"
```

Is it possible to use `-exec` instead?

Comment: Because the single-quoted string `'perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {}'` is not a valid command name. Remove the single quotes. (For efficiency, maybe also replace `\;` with `+`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command like

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec 'perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {}' \;
```

will cause the `find` program to receive these arguments (each on a separate line, without escaping):

```
find
.
-name
*.tex
-exec
perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {}
;
```

That is, the single quotes make the entire intended `perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {}` command into a single command-line argument.

However, `find` is not designed to work with that. It expects separate arguments instead:

```
find
.
-name
*.tex
-exec
perl
-0777
-pi
-e
s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g
{}
;
```

When `find` parses its arguments and finds a `-exec` argument, it will treat everything from there until either `;` or `+` as the command template. Within each token, `{}` will be replaced with a filename from the actual search process, and then these tokens represent the command that will be run.

Thus, without quotes, the commands will look like `perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g' colophon.tex`, (supposing that we re-constitute a command line that would tokenize the same way; of course, this is not necessary, since `find` already has the pre-processed tokens required to make a system call).

With quotes, the commands will look like in the error message: the TeX filenames were interpolated into the command, but the command is still a *single shell token* which doesn't match the name of any program (hence, "No such file or directory"). It is the same as how explicitly typing `'perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\\%\\%if.+?\\%\\%fi//g" ./colophon.tex'` (with the single quotes) at the command prompt wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {} \;
```

(only one command at once)

or

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\%\%if.+?\%\%fi//g" {} +
```

to run multiple commands at once.

(remove single 'quotes')